# XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to open a workbook through xlrd.

```
import xlrd
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("D:\Book1.xlsx")
```

But this is throwing error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\testuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NewPythonProject\src\newpythonproject.py", line 18, i`enter code here`n <module>
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("D:\Book1.xlsx")


File "D:\xlrd-0.7.1\xlrd\__init__.py", line 429, in open_workbook
biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)


File "D:\xlrd-0.7.1\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1545, in getbof
bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])


 File "D:\xlrd-0.7.1\xlrd\__init__.py", line 1539, in bof_error
raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found 'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00'
```

I am running this in netbeans with python plugin. If the version of xlrd is the issue I need a link to download latest version of xlrd in windows. Help me with the situation.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using xlrd-0.7.1 which is rather old - the latest version is xlrd-0.9.3. My testing shows that 0.7.1 can not open `.xlxs` files that can be opened using 0.9.3, so it's time for you to upgrade.

You can get it from PyPI: [xlrd-0.9.3](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.9.3.tar.gz). I don't think that a MSI is available, but you should be able to install it by first extracting the tarball and then running `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I tried using version 0.9.3 and 1.0.0. Both version gave me the same error as above `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '...'`

Comment: @Alex: there could be many reasons for that. Is your .xlxs file valid? Can it be opened in Excel or LibreOffice?

Comment: I am able to open it in excel, but I do get a warning saying the file may be corrupted before opening in excel.

Comment: @Alex: I think that's the problem then. If it is a one off file you could resave it to ensure that a valid file is created. What file signature is reported as "found"?

Comment: In my case the error was that I was using read_excel with a csv file